# Connect DocuSign XSD

Tags: docusignapi

I would like to implement the DocuSign Connect as a rest listener.

I cannot find anywhere a complete documentation of the xml schema that the listener will receive.

I know that there is an example in the pdf:

http://764be237d39fdfa0985f-37a6c1f0731907180d9764651d02bea9.r5.cf2.rackcdn.com/DocuSign_Connect_Service_Guide.pdf

but I am wondering if there is a more formal description like for example an xsd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also reference the complete XSD here: https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/schema/dsx.xsd

Answer (score 4):

Each Connect message will contain an **EnvelopeStatus** object and **DocumentPDF** objects -- the full structure of these objects is specified in the DocuSign WSDL:   https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/schema/dsapi.wsdl.

Taken from the DocuSign Connect Service Guide (http://764be237d39fdfa0985f-37a6c1f0731907180d9764651d02bea9.r5.cf2.rackcdn.com/DocuSign_Connect_Service_Guide.pdf):

```
"The XML post from DocuSign contains the EnvelopeStatus object along with DocumentPDF objects, if the configuration has the checkbox to include the push of the documents. 

The DocuSign 3.0 API WSDL file that contains definitions for both structures is located on the DocuSign website. It can be found at: https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx?wsdl."
```